# What is the story behind 逐日移山?

Tags: translation, word, culture

I read the following on social media which is provided in both Chinese and English, and it looks like the Chinese is the original and the English the translation:

热爱各有不同，青年本该如此，每一代逐日移山的青年都有自己奋不顾身的热爱，每一份炽烈的热爱都值得被用心对待！

Love is different, as youth should be. Every generation of young people who move mountains day by day has their own passionate love, and every passionate love deserves to be treated with care!

My question: Why do the young people move mountains day by day?

Answer (score 10):

It is a combination of two idiom stories

> 逐日 = [夸父逐日](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%A4%B8%E7%88%B6%E9%80%90%E6%97%A5/79883)

> “夸父逐日”的意思是比喻人有大志，也比喻不自量力

> 移山 = [愚公移山](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%84%9A%E5%85%AC%E7%A7%BB%E5%B1%B1/8262?fromModule=lemma_search-box)

> 文章叙述了愚公不畏艰难，坚持不懈，挖山不止，最终感动天帝而将山挪走的故事

"夸父(Kua Fu) 逐日 (chasing the sun)" describes "chasing a goal with determination even if it is an impossible goal"

"愚公(Yu Gong)移山 (moving the mountain)" describes "persisting on work toward a grand goal even if it seems unattainable"

> 热爱各有不同，青年本该如此，每一代[**逐日移山**]的青年都有自己奋不顾身的热爱，每一份炽烈的热爱都值得被用心对待！

> Passions are all different, and youth should be like this. Every generation of young people who [**persistently chase their dreams**] have their own all-consuming passion, and every burning passion deserves to be treated with care!

Comment: There's lots of helpful background info, in English, on these two 成语 (chengyu) here: https://laowaichengyuguide.com/entry/%E5%A4%B8%E7%88%B6%E9%80%90%E6%97%A5
https://laowaichengyuguide.com/entry/%E6%84%9A%E5%85%AC%E7%A7%BB%E5%B1%B1

Comment: Is this a commonly done thing, to combine two different chengyu like this?

Comment: @goPlayerJuggler It is not a common thing, you need to find  two idioms that are unique enough to allow people to recognize them by just looking at half of it, but combining two stories into one single idiom is very common, e.g. 斷袖分桃 contains two stories but is considered one idiom

Comment: How come they used "day by day"?

Comment: They mistakenly treat 逐日 as an adverb "day by day",  but 逐日 is actually a verb phrase "chase the sun" in this context

Comment: About the idioms that contain two stories at the same time, I might offer some more if you think they are the right ones: 悬梁刺股 沉鱼落雁 结草衔环.

Comment: Is it possible that the translator thinks it is a great task to remove a mountain day by day? And so does the reader?